# better practice for python method prototype design

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have to provide a python sdk, and now am in a dilemma about how should I design the method.

Just to say that, the function name is `func`, the `func` has to accept about 10 params. I know we can define the function like this way:

```
def func(para0, para1, para2, para3, para4, para5, para6, para7, para8, para9)
```

or

```
def func(obj_param)
```

and the `obj_param` is designed as a class instance which contains 
`para0` ~ `para9`.

Then which is the pythonic way? or both is OK?

Base on @deceze's question, I add some restrictions:`para0`~`para9` names are literally(cannot change to other name), and `para0` ~`param6` are mandatory, the left are optional.

Comment: Are all of them mandatory or optional? Are some optional and others mandatory? Are they very distinct parameters, or are they pretty literally param0-9 (a list really)? – How to design an API largely depends on the specifics of it, there's no generic answer.

Comment: There is a simple test - you could write some use-cases with this method and see, if it easy to read / debug / improve such method call. As for me, the more parameters a function accepts - the harder it becomes to use.

Comment: Follow up: what do these parameters represent? I mean, are they *literally* called "param0"?! That's terrifically unhelpful naming. Does that mean you're really just accepting a list of stuff that needs to be at least 7 items long...?

Comment: These can be literally called 'bill_title', 'bill_price' and so on, here para0 is just an example

Comment: If you create a structure for the parameters ([**`namedtuple`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) perhaps), you could then put the function on the class as a method instead. See the refactoring [Introduce  Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html), and the code smell [Lazy Class](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/lazy-class).

Answer (score 3):

you can use `kwargs` instead and extract the parameters for the dictionary. I find it a better solution than defining an object

`def func(**kwargs)`

Comment: It's the most pythonic too

Comment: @Mr.E, it depends. Probably, there will be other functions with same parameters - then it is better to extract them into a class.

Comment: This means you also *need* to pass all arguments as keyword arguments; this may or may not be desirable and can get extremely verbose on the calling side for 10 parameters.

Comment: @Mr.E Most Pythonic: Explict is better than implicit.

Answer (score 1):

There are few choices for you.
You can either use

```
def foo(my_list):  # pass a list as an argument and iterate over elements
    pass
```

or

```
def bar(*args):  # pass only arguments
    pass
# example
bar("text1", "text2", 2, 3)
```

or

```
def foobar(**kwargs):  # pass keyword arguments
    for key in kwargs:
        print(key, str(kwargs[key]))  # will print key and value

# example
>>foobar(name="My name" surname="my last name", age=24, weight=80)
('name', 'My name')
('surname', 'my last name')
('age', '24')
('weight', '80')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it depends of the parameters and what you want to do with them.

For example let's say your function takes 10 parameters to create and save a model with 10 fields, then the proper way would be for example:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    model = Model(**kwargs)
    model.save()
```

Then let's imagine the first parameter is actually the class of the model, then it would be:

```
def func(Class, **kwargs):
    model = Class(**kwargs)
    model.save()
```

Now imagine that all the parameters are instances of models and you want to return some composition, then the most logic would be:

```
def func(*args):
    average = 0
    for inst in *args:
        average += inst.value
    return average
```

Now imagine the parameters are parameters to build a request, and your function's purpose is to return a hash of the request (for example to roughly identify a user without a proper authentication system), then the separation of concerns would make it logical to build the request object outside of the function, and make the function only return the hash, so that you can build requests from other parts of your code and so that you could have different kinds of request objects. Then the function would be like:

```
def func(request):
    ...
```